Fetch records based on parent table along with 2 unrelated child tables
I have a parent table named as "P" and have a primary key association in 2 child tables like child 1(C1) and child 2(C2), both these child tables are unrelated.
If I have total 10 records in parent table and 5 records in child 1 and 8 records in child 2 matching the parent table, I need the output of total 13 records.
Current problem:
With Inner join
I only get 5 records total
With left join,
I get 10 records non matching parent table records.
Postgres SQL
SELECT p.*, 
       c1.*, 
       c2.*
FROM parent p
LEFT JOIN child1 c1 ON p.id = c1.parent_id
LEFT JOIN child2 c2 ON p.id = c2.parent_id;

Parent table

child table one

child table two

Expectation

Question:

How do I fetch these 13 records from the query ?
If I apply limit as 8 I should get the 5 records from child 1 and 8 from child 2.

I cannot use a Union of because I am using Spring boot JPA,Hibernate for this and not sure if JPA supports UNION.
I need to do this via Query or JPA,Hibernate.

Please don't post images of items that can be adequately presented as text. In this case, use the appropriate markup to show the table contents and expected result. If you only want the parent rows that have child records (which is what you show as the expected result), then add WHERE c1.id IS NOT NULL OR c2.id IS NOT NULL to the query..

@JohnH Please add this as an answer I will accept it , this worked

I'm not sure that my comment completely addresses the question. It works fine if there is never more than one corresponding row in each child table; however, your post doesn't describe the desired result when more than one corresponding row occurs in either (or both) child tables.
